# jquery is not working when show table from ajax request page

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using Datatable Plug-ins. When i am showing table from ajax request page jquery function is not working.

`$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('#example').DataTable();
});`

Comment: What does your table looks like? You should add more code, so we can help you.

Comment: You need to give us more details, code example (html + js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `$('#example').DataTable();` after your ajax call is finished (on success function for example).